# Android looping through cursor taking a lot of time

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Andorid cursor containing 33 columns and 10 rows; but iterating through it is taking a lot of time on android device.

```
curOutputData.moveToFirst();
        while(curOutputData.isAfterLast()==false);
        {
        //  curOutputData.moveToFirst();
            //curOutputData.moveToNext();
            System.out.println("i am writing data.."+rowIdx);
            cellIdx = 0;
            Row hssfRow = sheet1.createRow(rowIdx++);
            for(int j=0; j<curOutputData.getColumnCount();j++)
            {
                Cell hssfCell = hssfRow.createCell(cellIdx++);
                //String cellValue = curOutputData.getString(j);
                hssfCell.setCellValue(curOutputData.getString(j));
                //System.out.println("cellvalue==="+cellValue);
            }

            curOutputData.moveToNext();
        }
```

i am doing this to generate an excel file. Please advice where i am going wrong. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Put some traces to see which line of code takes time in your loop

Comment: I have tried doing that but it never goes into the while loop or taking too long to print any thing...i.e it never writes "I am writing data"..

Answer (score 3):

You could start by replacing moveToFirst + while(!isAfterLast) + moveToNext by a single `while(curOutputData.moveToNext())` which is the same and saves you one call to isAfterLast at each iteration.

Then, I recommend using `traceview` to identify where you spend time. It could be the cursor, but it could also be your excel formatter. (That could also be quickly identified by commenting the excel part for a test).

(Also, that all depends on what you mean by 'taking a lot of time')

Remark : why use cellIdx and j, which have the same value and the same meaning ?

Answer (score 0):

The other answer has one good point, 
and in addition

```
for(int j=0; j < curOutputData.getColumnCount(); j++)
```

every iteration the command `curOutputData.getColumnCount()` is executed. If the result does not change during the loop, you should store the value in an integer before the loop.

```
int size = curOutputData.getColumnCount();
for(int j=0; j < size; j++)
```

you could also create the `Cell hssfCell` reference before the loop so that it need not be allocated every loop (not sure how good the dalvik optimizes)